# Answering a "green" question.

Tags: discussion

I often ask myself when should I answer a question where the OP has already accepted an answer. I sometimes feel some more can be added to help the OP, or that some of his inquiries haven't been addressed, although he accepted an answer.

Is it OK to answer a question where the OP has accepted an answer?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I agree with Qiaochu that answering a question with an accepted answer is perfectly alright. I'd like to add that an answer is not just there to help the OP, but rather to help anyone who is stuck on/interested in/wondering about the same thing, including people who may stumble upon the question long after it is first asked. Just because an accepted answer contained enough detail and explained enough to help one person, doesn't mean it will satisfy everyone!

Answer (score 20):

I can't think of a reason not to.

Answer (score 7):

There is even the Populist badge for outscoring an accepted answer.